# React-hook-form with material-ui does not show errors from rules

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm new to using react-hook-form and after lots of research I stil cannot understand what I'm I doing wrong. I did a sandbox in which I have a simple input number.

**How I would like my form to behave :** I want the default value (16) to show and I want the errors below the input to show when the number does not respect the given rules (when the number is not between 16-99).

Can someone please help me understand? I'm going crazy! :s

Here is the sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-northcutt-8wt6p?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the value of TextField's value to render's parameter value. Also add submit button in order the validation work.

I've forked your code for detailed code
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-fire-eroqv

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! As for the onChange event you made me realised when suggested to add the submit button that my form was validating on submit, the default behavior of react-hook-form. To change this to an "onchange" event handler I simply updated de defaultValues object to `mode: :onChange"` in the useForm() initialisation!